# How to check if newer version of Intel IPP is available?

Tags: intel-ipp

In order to check for newer version, one has to know the current version the program is running with and the latest version available for download.

The current version can be seen from the install path, for example: /opt/intel/ipp/6.1.5.061/

The latest version can be seen by checking the available samples, for example: http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/1911/l_ipp-samples_p_6.1.6.073.tgz
Is there an "official" place for this?

How to get this values programmatically?

Notes:

ippGetLibVersion() returns just "6.1"

latest version can be seen with:
curl -s ttp://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-code-samples/ | grep "l_ipp-samples_p"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible.

There is no known way to check the exact current version and the latest available.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get the IPP version automaticaly? You can keep the last version number on you site, and tell the application to check the version from you site. You application is linked with particular version of IPP so you know the version it works with.

Comment: Yes, the latest version number can and should be kept on a website, but I think the right place for this is in a known place on the Intel web site. I can't find that place.

Comment: Yes, the application is linked with a particular version, but the question is: how to find out which one programmatically?